# Игра "Морской бой"

Tags: c++builder

Нужно реализовать игру морской бой, у кого-то есть исходники? Как лучше ее реализовать?
Массивом или таблицей?
Для курсовой нужно.

Comment: В метку требуемый язык программирования добавьте!

Answer (score 1):

[Консольный морской бой](http://shatalov.su/cpp_primer/sea_battle.php).

Реализовывать проще таблицей, то есть двумерным массивом, поскольку это более естественно отвечает топологии задачи.